# How to obtain sticky header table?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, yeoman

I am testing [floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) and [StickyTableHeaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) for the sticky table header effect and it works just fine. If wrap the table with a div with an **ng-if** angular directive it doesn't work anymore and I don't have any errors in the console. My app is a YeoMan project.
If I use other angular directives it works, why is breaking with **ng-if** ?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-if="1 === 1">
        <table class="table table-striped sticky-header">
           ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    /*floatThead script
            or
      stickyTableHeaders script
    */
</script>
```

**Example**

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/ptongalex/pen/JGMBNZ) here it works, but in my YeoMan project it doesn`t !

Comment: Why do you need the div there in the first place why not just put the ng-if on the table? Also do you have a working example of the issue or debugging info anywhere?

Comment: Same thing...I tried that also and doesn't work ....(example: http://codepen.io/ptongalex/pen/JGMBNZ), on codepen it works, but in my YeoMan project it doesn`t !

Comment: Also does it have the same problem with ng-show?

Comment: Nope, it works, but I can't use ng-show, because the table is loaded in the dom and then is not displayed....so the pageload is high !!

Comment: Well ng-if creates it removes it then recreates it so.......

Comment: " differs from ngShow and ngHide in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: So why in codepen is working and in my app it doesn't ?

Comment: and ng-show works locally but not ng-if right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101319/discussion-between-jackie-and-vlad-radulescu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess your JS libs got out of order. This can happen on occasion and sometimes does not trigger an error message.